# Is there a way to get all tweets from twitter for a specified user?

Tags: php, twitter

I wanted to write a function for grabbing all tweets for specified user, but it returns only 20 most recent.

I came up with something like that:

```
function getTweets($user) {

    $page = file_get_contents("http://twitter.com/{$user}");
    $from = strpos($page, "<ol id='timeline' class='statuses'>");
    $to = strpos($page, "</ol>");
    $length = $to - $from;
    $page =substr($page, $from, $length);
    echo $page;
}

getTweets('user_name');
```

Is there a way to get round that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Twitter has an [API](http://developer.twitter.com/doc) that you should be querying to retrieve data such as tweets. It is far more efficient than crawling the HTML.

The [statuses/user_timeline](http://developer.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) API service returns a list of tweets from any non-protected user. Here's an [example](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?id=frkt_) of this service, configured to retrieve tweets for the user FRKT_ (that's me). You can customize the data it returns in many ways, such as by appending the `count` variable to the URL [like so](http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?id=frkt_&count=20) to specify how many tweets you'd like to retrieve.

You should use an XML parser such as [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) rather than miscellaneous string functions such as `strpos` like you demonstrated to parse the data returned from the API.

Comment: Damn. I missed the `count` parameter. I think, that should do the trick. Now I will definitely use the Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter Libraries](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries) has libs for php listed. If you can grab a single users all tweets or not I'm afraid I don't know but the libs should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

They only return a maximum of 3200 tweets per user by calling [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline), for more info look here:
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1157

Comment: So that means, that `count` argument sets not only a small limit, but even it's max. is a limit to normal request?

Comment: `count` is used to indicate how many tweets you want to fetch per page, then you use `since_id` and/or `max_id` to navigate through the results. Look at their pagination guideline: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines