# How to get 'many' tweets from a user using Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter

There are some questions discuss about how to use Twitter API to get tweets from a user. (e.g., [Twitter API getting any user's all tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083982/twitter-api-getting-any-users-all-tweets), [Is there a way to get all tweets from twitter for a specified user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092838/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-tweets-from-twitter-for-a-specified-user))

I know I should use [user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline). But my questions is that Twitter put a rate limit, if I want to download say 1000 tweets a time, it will give me an error.

In the following code I made separate requests to the API and sleep several minutes between each request, but it still doesn't work.

```
for p in range(1, 6):
    params['page'] = p
    url = base_url + urllib.urlencode(params)

    r = requests.get(url)
    j = simplejson.loads(r.content)

    for item in j:
       # do something to tweets

time.sleep(180)
```

Any idea for work around? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the [streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods) using e.g. [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy), and filter the API `statuses` method with one or more user IDs. The advantage to this method is that the streaming API isn't rate-limited. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111346/how-to-use-the-count-parameter-in-tweepys-streaming-api) should get you up and running with Tweepy and the streaming API.